# Comparing similar columns by using max(date)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
aaa         bbbb        ccc         1/1/16
aaa         bbbb        ddd         2/1/16
abc         def         ghi         1/1/16
abc         def         ihg         2/1/16
```

I want the output to be

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3    Column 4
aaa         bbbb        ddd         2/1/16
abc         def         ihg         2/1/16
```

That is I want the result as (column1,2,3) and max(column4).
I am using SQL Server! How can I achieve this?

Comment: how are you choosing the values for `Column 3`?

Comment: By using max(column 4)

Comment: That's not an answer for choosing the value for column 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want, but this produces your expected output:

```
select * from mytable
where column4 = (select max(column4) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your description of what you want does not match the data.  You seem to want each row which has the maximum date in col4 for pairs of col1 and col2.

You can get this using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col4 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

If the interpretation of the question is that you want the rows with the maximum *overall* value of column 4:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (order by col4 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```